# Has Xcode permanently screwed up my ability to target WatchKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch app. Recently, Xcode and the Simulator started failing to load the WatchKit App on the Watch Simulator. It would only show a black screen, and occasionally crash to exit.

Not sure why, and none of the google suggestions have helped.

I thought I'd create a new project, to see if I could compare settings. But when I add the WatchKit target to the project, Xcode only gives me a scheme to run the WatchKit app on "My Mac" as a destination.

[image: Destination of WatchKit App is "My Mac"]

Try as I might, I can't get a device to show up. The Build Settings specify an iOS Base SDK, and iOS as the Supported Platforms for all targets.

Is this a pull the plug and re-install Xcode situation? Strange thing is its a relatively new installation and I'll I've done is code; no messing around with any behind the scenes files. As I'm having trouble with the Watch Simulator in general, I guess it's a deep issue which needs a 'start over' approach- does anyone please have any steps I might try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to a bug in XCode.

See the bug report here: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/19776564

Best option is to close XCode then trash as much of your

- Derived Data,
- Simulator working folders,
- other temporary/build folders; and
- xcuserdata files

as possible (preferably copy them to a safe place from which they can be restored first). Then restart XCode.

Took a long time to resolve this one. XCode 6 and XCode 7 are both of very poor quality.